# PHPSESSID changes on every request instead of persisting

Tags: php, ios, session

I have an iOS app sending requests to a PHP based web service , Everything used to work just fine but lately i've been losing sessions all the time.

I've checked the cookies and noticed that PHPSESSID changes on EVERY request i send , instead of using the same one,

After Request #1: `I am a cookie ! PHPSESSID = 9lsv80co96op3mg4tffpuoav22` 
After Request #2: `I am a cookie ! PHPSESSID = nn3f3v32j598jbhsof0admc442`

I wanted to know if there is any way to persist the session id, or i just have to save it and post it every time? I would rather make this a server-side solution since if i would have to chnage something in the app itself, it would take a week to ten days for Apple to approve it.

If there's any configuration that would help me with retaining the PHPSESSID value It would be very helpful for me.

Would appreciate your help. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your application isn't holding the cookies that PHP is sending with the PHPSESSID so it's generating a new session id for each request.

Comment: Thanks, i hoped i wouldn't have to change my source code but saving PHPSESSID and using it in each request is the safest way. Thanks for trying to help :)

Comment: Please help me how can I fix this