# AXIOS: Cookie value changes on every request

Tags: vue.js, cookies, axios

Im working on a login page,

I have 2 api:

api1 = for authentication of credential

api2 = for getting user info

the first request is fine, but the second request always fails, when I checked the response headers the **PHPSESSID** on **set-cookie** changed.

I use `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true` but didn't work

not sure what to do on this.

I hope you can help me.

thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what has the PHPSESSID to do with the request failing. Do you need to send the PHPSESSID to authenticate for the second request?

Comment: Seems to me that is backend problem.

Comment: @sebasaenz thats the value of the set-cookie, I guess yes, heres a same issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/11054440/10073602

Comment: @GabrielWillemann when I open the api on separate tabs it displays the data, can t find any solution on this online